# How did 鳥 end up a Kangxi radical but not 烏?

Tags: etymology, radicals, strokes

烏, *wū*, crow, 10 strokes, 灬 radical
鳥, *niǎo*, bird, 11 strokes, 鳥 radical

All the way since at least seal script, [鳥](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/File:%E9%B3%A5-seal.svg) seems like just [烏](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/File:%E7%83%8F-seal.svg) with an additional stroke. They both describe birds in one way or another. Why was 烏 not used as the building block, as a separate radical, or even as a –1 stroke variant of 鳥?

Answer (score 3):

Radicals are not building blocks of characters, they're dictionary entry organisation headers. They're equivalent to the first letter in an English word. The radicals are *chosen* so that some characters are easily and obviously grouped under these headers, but some radicals are very arbitrary (see e.g. [Radical 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_4) and the characters grouped under it).

The optimisation of a Chinese dictionary (at least the Kangxi dictionary) is concerned about how to organise 50,000 characters whilst choosing the number of appropriate dictionary headings (*radicals*) to split these 50,000 characters under.

In this light,「烏」is less suitable than「鳥」as a header, because many more characters are clearly grouped under「鳥」rather than「烏」. However, if one looks at *Shuowen Jiezi*, [which has 540 radicals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Shuowen_Jiezi_radicals) (as opposed to Kangxi's 214), one has more leeway in including radicals; indeed, *Shuowen* has「烏」as a radical.

Answer (score 0):

烏 specifically referring to 'crow'

鳥 referring to 'bird' in general.

There are many 'bird' related characters, but I don't know any 'crow' related character

鴨(duck)、鵝(goose)、鶴(crane)、鷹(eagle)、鴉(crow) are all bird, but only 鴉 is crow

*烏 also means 'black' because all crows are black, we even have an idiom '天下烏鴉一般黑' pointing out this fact*